# How to call java methods in xhtml

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I could observe in a Spring project with Primefaces that java methods were called directly in the xhtml without using servlets.

ex:

- *< Some_Html_Object [...] onclick = "**${FooClass.fooAction()}**" />*
- *< Some_Html_Object [...] value="**${FooClass.fooParameter}**" />*

How do you configure your Spring project to do this? Do you have tutorials? 
Is it possible to implement it for a J2E project?

Ps : I'm a begginner in Spring.

Thank

Comment: Any basic jsf tutorial teaches you these jsf basics. Adding spring can then be read in many other existing tutorials in the internet. Just use a search engine.

Comment: I searched but the search on "spring call java method html" returns pages on javaspring methods.


i'm beginner in spring/j2e ( openclassroom formation)
I've only had extensive training in Java/c++, hence my question.

Comment: Hi, [ask]  states that you should mention what you searched, keep track and mention that in your questions. In this case, your search was wrong since you thught it was called from html (while tagging xhtml and primefaces). Learning the basics that PrimeFaces is JSF based and then learning the basics of JSF would have given you 100% of what is in the answer. EVERY jsf tutorial (even the 10 year old ones) would have.E.g. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=call+java+method+from+xhtml+jsf+spring

Comment: And the answer below only mentions 10% of all options. Waaaaaay more too it and all already available in duplicate Q/A in stackoverflow, but you've got to always first try to find the basics behind what you try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JSF page you can call the methods from a bean by using the [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm).

As an example in a non Spring JEE application that is not injecting any Spring Beans. However you can use CDI in a Spring project.

```
  @Named
  @ViewScoped

  public class TestBean implements Serializable{

  private String documentTitle;
  private String documentURL;
  private ArrayList<ACMSSearchResults> acmsResults = new ArrayList<>();

  public ACMSSearch(){}

  public String getDocumentTitle() {
    return documentTitle;
  }

  public void setDocumentTitle(String title) {
    documentTitle = title;
  }  
}
```

You can call a method from the bean in the JSF page using the expression language

```
<p:label value="#{testBean.documentTitle}"/>
```

A good tutorial for configuring Spring to work with JSF look [HERE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jsf)